# Moving by word (w/b) and staying within the line

Tags: regular-expression, cursor-movement

### Background

I'm attempting to remap the arrow keys to move by word while staying within the current line. I.e. I'm looking for a behavior similar to `w` and `b`, but that acts like `h` and `l` in the sense that it doesn't move to a line above or below. For moving right, I have the current solution:

```
nnoremap <expr> <Right> getline('.')[col('.')-1:] =~# '\s\S' ? 'w' : '$'
```

It gets most of the way there, but since `\s\S` is only looking to see if there are more whitespaces, the behavior breaks down at the end of a line. For instance, it misses `instrs` in the following example line:`

```
'>'::xs -> parse_chars xs ((Next 1)::instrs)
```

### Question

How do I get the behavior I'm looking for? Is there any way to regex match a "vim word" to get the desired behavior?

### Edit

I'm aware that this is technically possible by a short script using `norm`, like below:

```
function! CustomRight()
    let last = line('.')
    norm w
    if line('.') != last
        norm b$
    endif
endfunction
```

But this isn't ideal, since `norm` brings you into normal mode. So it wouldn't work in visual mode.

Comment: Not exactly sure, but I would try `nnoremap <expr> <Right> getline('.')[col('.')-1:] =~# '\<' ? 'w' : '$'`  so check if there is a word-boundary atom anywhere on the right

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I guess `\<` must be a vim-regex dialect for something other than what vim considers to be words (in w and b)? It doesn't seem to work correctly near the end of some lines. For  instance, If I try it on the solution you posted it will skip from the first apostrophe in  `... w' : '$'` to the end of the line.

Comment: well, yes, those are technically not beginning of words :). BTW: Check the help for any unknown regex atom like this: `:h /\<`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with:

```
:nnoremap <expr> <Right> col('.') == (col('$') - 1) \|\| getline('.')[col('.')-1:] =~# '^[^[:keyword:]]\+$' ? '$' : 'w'
```

Unfortunately it still doesn't work quite right, so I came up with this:

```
:nnoremap <expr> <Right> col('.') == (col('$') - 1) \|\| getline('.')[col('.')-1:] =~# '^[^[:keyword:]]\+\s*$\\|^\k\+\s*$' ? '$' : 'w'
```

Comment: Huh, I thought there were \w and \W atoms for word and WORD characters

Comment: @D.BenKnoble There are, and I probably misunderstood mortelsson's requirements. It can be adjusted, though. (Although the `w` and `b` commands do rely on `'iskeyword'`.)

Comment: you might simply try the `\<` beginning of word atom

Comment: The second solution seems to do the trick. Very nice!